# Deleting Your Own Questions and Answer

Tags: support, deleted-posts

When I delete my own Questions / Answers will the reputation changes because of up-votes/down-votes on the Particular Question/Answer be reversed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes*. Reputation changes because of up-votes/down-votes on the Particular Question/Answer will be reversed.

However, deleted questions still count when the system is looking at how many poor quality questions you may have asked.

<sup>/* If the post is more than 60 days old and has a score of 3+ you *don't* lose the reputation.</sup>

Comment: re footnote: sounds like a loophole to get the [Disciplined](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/37/disciplined) badge without rep cost. Why shouldn't one lose rep on deletion of old posts?

Comment: @ShawnChin - now that is a can of worms you're opening there.

Comment: @ShawnChin - start here for some background - http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/se-podcast-32-jarrod-dixon-and-josh-heyer - basically changes were made (instant rep recalcs) which made rep loss from post deletion more obvious. To say that some people complained would be an understatement.